# Regular expression to validate email address taking into consideration there may be trimming needed at start or end

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation, client-side

Currently I have a regular expression validator like so

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator EnableClientScript="true" 
    ValidationGroup="Email" class="errorMessages" ID="revEmail" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Your email address does not appear to be of a valid form."
    ControlToValidate="txtEmail" 
    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
   * Email format is invalid.
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

This works okay for things like `"abc@yahoo.com"`

However, many users are cutting and pasting their emails in so sometimes it may be 
`"abc@yahoo.com "` or `" abc@yahoo.com"`.

At this point it rightly invalidates the entry.

Doing a bit of googling, it seems `"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"` is the standard way to validate emails. However, can anyone help me modify the regular expression to accept situations like `"abc@yahoo.com "`?

I do not want to do this validation on the server side. I have seperate server side validation which will trim the email before saving it to the database.

Comment: "I do not want to do this validation on the server side"... huh? but `EnableClientScript` is `false`. It is running on the server.

Comment: oops, didn't realize it was actually posting back. Ok please assume that EnableClientScript is actually true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\s` in regex to find spaces and `*` to match zero or more. So wrapping your expression with `\s*...\s*` will accept unlimited number of spaces surrounding your expression. Putting this together with the expression you already have is:

```
\s*\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*
```